# Appending to an array in bash, why this isn't working?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying from a list of files with a pattern correctly matched by regex to check whether this value is in my array, if not, append it.

Unfortunately, this code that I build up inspired by some stack overflow post doesn't work (nothing is happened, the =~ doesn't seem to find the bash_rematch, and also it doesn't output anything?

```
sample_array=() #creating the array
for context_files in data/*.txt.gz # checking all the different samples id we have
do 
    [[ $context_files =~ SL[0-9]{6} ]]
    echo 'context file:' "$context_files"
    
    echo 'rematch:' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    
    if ! [[ " ${sample_array[*]} " =~ (^|[[:space:]])"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"($|[[:space:]])  ]]; then
        echo 'condition matched'
        echo 'rematch:' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        sample_array+=(" ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} ")
        
    fi
done
echo "${sample_array[*]}"
```

replacing this code by

```
sample_array=() #creating the array
for context_files in data/*.txt.gz # checking all the different samples id we have
do 
    [[ $context_files =~ SL[0-9]{6} ]]
    echo 'context file:' "$context_files"
    
    echo 'rematch:' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    
    if ! [[ " ${sample_array[*]} " == "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"  ]]; then
        echo 'condition matched'
        echo 'rematch:' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        sample_array+=(" ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} ")
        
    fi
done
echo "${sample_array[*]}"
```

will this time add all the variable
output :

```
A B A B A B
```

I probably don't get something in how the if is managed and/or how the regex lookup in a bash array is to be made but I'd gladly get some help!

Comment: Are you open to other ways to write this, or do you want help with the script as written? The reason I ask is I'd probably tackle this differently. This looks like "C style" scripting with explicit loops and array management. A more idiomatic shell scripting approach would manipulate streams of text data using pipelines with sed, awk, sort, uniq, and the like.

Comment: Please help us reproduce your problem. We don't have your `data/` directory. Your output `A B A B A B` cannot be produced by this code since all array entries have to be of the form `SL123456`. Please add the output of `ls -1 data/*.txt.gz` and add the actual output of the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The second match is negated, so in order to enter the *then* part, the match needs to fail. A failed match resets $BASH_REMATCH.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
sample_array=()
for context_files in data/SL{111111,222222,333333,111111,222222}.txt.gz ; do 
    [[ $context_files =~ SL[0-9]{6} ]]
    match=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    echo 'context file:' "$context_files"
    echo 'rematch:' "$match"
    if ! [[ " ${sample_array[*]} " =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$match"($|[[:space:]])  ]]; then
        echo 'condition matched'
        echo 'rematch:' "$match"
        sample_array+=(" $match ")
        
    fi
done
echo "${sample_array[*]}"
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if you added a solution to the problem, for instance using `sample=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` directly after the first `if` and then using `$sample` instead of `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely alternative solution in bash-style like John Kugelman suggested:

```
printf %s\\n data/*.txt.gz | grep -Eo 'SL[0-9]{6}' | sort -u
```

If you need the results in an array, use `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t array <(printf %s\\n data/*.txt.gz | grep -Eo 'SL[0-9]{6}' | sort -u)
```